# Isomorphism Of Cross Quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have two questions that I need help about.

1. Let $R$ and $S$ be rings, $I$ and $J$ ideals of $R$ and $S$
   respectively. Prove that $I\times J$ is an ideal of $R\times S$ and
   $(R\times S)/(I\times J)$ is isomorphic to $R/I \times S/J$.
2. What is $R/I$ in the following situation: $R = C[0,1]$, $I = \{ f\in R \mid f(1/2)=0 \}$

Comment: If my edit has misinterpreted any part of the problem, please feel free to correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Hint:** To see that $I\times J$ is an ideal of $R\times S$, just check the properties of ideals, remembering that every element of $R\times S$ is of the form $(r,s)$ with $r\in R$ and $s\in S$, and that addition and multiplication in $R\times S$ are computed componentwise. As for the quotient isomorphism, consider the [surjective] map
   \begin{align*}
   f : R\times S&\to R/I\times S/J\\
   (r,s)&\mapsto (r + I, s + J).
   \end{align*}
   Examine the kernel and apply the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Noether.27s_First_isomorphism_theorem_2).
2. **Hint:** I assume you mean $R = C[0,1] = \{f : [0,1]\to\Bbb R\mid f\textrm{ continuous}\}$ and $I = \{f\in R\mid f(1/2) = 0\}$ (you use $R$ twice in what looks like different ways without making a distinction). Consider the [surjective] map
   \begin{align*}
   \phi : R&\to\Bbb R\\
   f&\mapsto f(1/2).
   \end{align*}
   Again, examine the kernel and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Takeaway: the first isomorphism theorem is a very useful tool in understanding quotient rings.

Comment: thanks!, but in the second question i didnt understand how the first isomorphism theorem is going to help me, i need to determine what is the Quotient ring of R/I

Comment: The point of the hint is that $I = \ker\phi$.